# Как выбрать в тексте слова, которые состоят только из букв или цифр, используя regex

Tags: регулярные-выражения

У меня есть команда(строка):

```
"!создать привет21 приве+т4 привет8 +привет1 при14вет"
```

Мне нужно выбрать из этой строки слова, состоящие только из букв или цифр.
Для моего примера это будет: `привет21`, `привет8` и `при14вет`. Остальные мне не подходят, так как в них есть символ, который не относится к букве или цифре(в первом это `!`, в третьем и пятом - `+`).

Comment: Что такое "слово" в этом контексте? Буквы только русские?

Comment: @dIm0n набор букв и цифр. Английские и русские

Comment: Почему тогда `т4` и `приве` не надо найти? Это наборы буквы и цифр

Comment: @dIm0n тогда слово - это разделённое пробелами набор цифр и букв(англ и рус). Между ними '+', поэтому меня это не устраивает

Comment: Почему тогда `при14вет` надо найти? После него нет пробела

Comment: @dIm0n Ну оно тоже соответствует набору цифр и букв(англ и рус), хоть после него и не стоит пробел

Comment: *"слово - это разделённое пробелами набор цифр и букв"*, *"нужно выбрать из этой строки слова"*. *"Разделённое"*, значит окружённое пробелами? Если да, то `при14вет` не подходит по условию

Comment: @dIm0n Разделённое - это отделённое от других наборов цифр и букв(англ и рус) пробелом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так вот:

```
(?<=^|\h)[a-zA-Zа-яА-ЯёЁ\d]+(?=\h|$)
```

Тест https://regex101.com/r/ANxeVd/2

```
!создать привет21 приве+т4 привет8 +привет1 при14вет
1  2 приvет ёж1 ПРИвет  123/ 42
```

Comment: Та за шо минус?